# How do I hash a route in Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask, hash, routes, flask-sqlalchemy

My goal is pretty simple, I created a route that receives an ID.

```
@app.route('/afbase/<int:pid>', methods=["GET", "PATCH", "DELETE"])
# We defined the page that will retrieve some info
def show(pid):
    new_person = People.query.filter_by(pid=pid).first()
```

I don't want this ID to be shown to the final user. How do I hash the route or partially hash the route?

[image: current url screenshot]

This route will receive a variable called PID as you can see, this PID variable can be considered as an ID. Not case sensitive but it wouldn't be okay to show on the browser URL.

I tried using hashlib without much success.

Comment: Why don't you just create another method with the hash-ed url (with the `@app.route` decorator), which would call the real function, with the real id?

Comment: hashes are not reversible. How do you expect to get the PID at the client?

Comment: @Keith I`m the one sending him an exclusive view, I need no information from my final customers, I'm displaying a dynamic view for each client in my database. Since this info will be public (and it has to be since i want to make it as simple as possible) So... I'll send him a url that contains this specific pid. The problem is, other clients could just input a id in the url and access other customers areas, so i want this url from my print to be hashed 

I hope it makes sense, I'm a 2 month flask learner btw :D

Comment: If there's a good reason you don't want them to see each other's data, this definitely is not sufficient protection. Storing a UUID per customer would be better, but still not good; you need some kind of actual authentication if it's even remotely important. Also, `first()` implies multiple results could come through. `one()` would be more appropriate, since that identifier should be unique, and if for some reason it's not, a duplicate should result in an error on attempted access (so neither user with the duplicate identifier could potentially see the other's data).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `hashids` library to encode and decode integer ID's. First, `pip install hashids`. Then, create a few utility functions.

```
# utils.py
from flask import current_app
from hashids import Hashids

def create_hashid(id):
    hashids = Hashids(min_length=5, salt=current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    hashid = hashids.encode(id)
    return hashid

def decode_hashid(hashid):
    hashids = Hashids(min_length=5, salt=current_app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
    id = hashids.decode(hashid)
    return id
```

Next, create a global environment variable so you can call the create_hashid function from your jinja2 template:

```
# app.py
from utils import create_hashid
app.jinja_env.globals.update(create_hashid=create_hashid)
```

Here is how to call that function from the link in the template:

```
# index.html
<a href="{{ url_for('invoice.view_invoice', hashid=create_hashid(invoice.id) ) }}">View Invoice</a>
```

Finally, your view function:

```
# views.py
@blueprint.route('/dashboard/invoice/<hashid>')
@login_required
def view_invoice(hashid):
    invoice_id = decode_hashid(hashid)
    invoice = Invoice.query.filter_by(
        user_id=current_user.id,
        id=invoice_id
    ).first_or_404()

return render_template(
    'dashboard/invoice/view_invoice.html',
    invoice=invoice
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP has an answer already. Yet, I found an awesome Flask extension called [Flask-Hashids](https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Hashids/) which is basically based on [hashids](https://github.com/davidaurelio/hashids-python) used in Bob's answer, but more elegant.

A reproducible code

```py
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask_hashids import HashidMixin, Hashids
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret-key'
app.config['HASHIDS_SALT'] = 'must-be-different-from-SECRET_KEY'
app.config['HASHIDS_MIN_LENGTH'] = 16
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db_dev.sqlite3'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
hashids = Hashids(app)

class User(HashidMixin, db.Model): # Add the hashid mixin class
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)

    @property
    def url(self):
        # The HashidConverter encodes the given id to a hashid in the URL
        return url_for('user', user_id=self.id)

    def to_json(self):
        return {"id": self.hashid, "name": self.name}

@app.before_first_request
def create_user_table():
    db.create_all()
    # Add some dummy data
    db.session.add_all([User(name='John Doe'), User(name='Jane Doe')])
    db.session.commit()

@app.route("/user", methods=["GET"], strict_slashes=False)
def users():
    users = User.query.all()  # get all users
    return [user.to_json() for user in users], 200

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Output

```json
[
    {
        "id": "RxvDmWYG8neBo098", # Hashed ID
        "name": "John Doe"
    },
    {
        "id": "yaAxNdnWbYgk4oeZ", # Hashed ID
        "name": "Jane Doe"
    }
]
```

Or refer to the documentation [here](https://github.com/Pevtrick/Flask-Hashids/blob/main/README.md) and example [here](https://github.com/Pevtrick/Flask-Hashids/blob/main/examples/basic_crud/app.py)